# Why does the jquery.d.ts TypeScript definition file throw a compile error?

Tags: typescript

I have a basic MVC4 web project in VSTS 2012 to play around with TypeScript.

I installed this version of TypeScript: TypeScriptSetup.0.8.1.msi

I have the jquery.d.ts file from: http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fe3bc0bfce1f#typings%2fjquery.d.ts

I am getting compile errors on all "index signature" definitions.  The first compile error is with the JQueryAjaxSettings:

```
 headers?: { [key: any]: any; };
```

Here is the error:

```
Error 9 Index signatures may only take 'string' or 'number' as their parameter
C:\Development\TypeScript\ScriptGen\ScriptGen.Web\Scripts\jquery.d.ts 37 18 app.ts
```

The compiler doesn't like the **key** defined as type **any**.

Should I change the key type to string or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using an old version of jquery.d.ts. The compiler has changed since then to disallow `any` indexers. Any newer version of jquery.d.ts (e.g. [this one](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/92d9e637f6e1#typings/jquery.d.ts)) will work fine, or you can just change that `any` to `string` if you like (there have been multiple other fixes in that file in the interim you might want, though).

Comment: Ha, wow, it was definitely not obvious in the CodePlex UI that I was viewing an outdated version of the code. I guess I clicked in from stale search results. Thanks!

Comment: I ran into the same issue last week, but I can't just take the new CodePlex version because I made other custom modifications for Deferred support. As Ryan mentioned, I just updated all the key: any to key: string.

Comment: Accidentally picked up an old version of the definitions, via an old link. This let me know what I had missed. Cheers.